# certain special characters (ie '<>' or '=>') the data gets converted to & format when pasted into cell in telerik grid view

Tags: database, winforms, sql-server-2008, telerik, telerik-grid

When I paste a value into a cell that has a special character ( > or <= ) it looks fine, but when they close and reopen the grid it shows up with the &

This is happening in telerik grid view control for winforms.And the cell in inserted into database which column is nvarchar().

Like I paste <10 and it converted to <10

[image: Grid value changed]

Comment: Let me guess somewhere in the code you pass arguments as XML  and some characters are changed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: The problems shows when I paste this type of value but not showing when I typed them. Any clue or link please?

Comment: What OS you use, and check `clipboard` program settings?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: As I said check clipboard settings or maybe your application escape characters